# Как сделать боковое отражение элемента на CSS

Tags: html, css

Суть в картинке, как добавить блокам боковые отражения?
Пробовал вариант с box-reflect примененный к основному div, но он отражает только сам блок (то есть не содержащийся в нем контент) да еще и делает это зеркально.
Еще один вариант - это создание копий div-ов с карточками, прицепление их псевдоэлементами, а затем изменение opacity и позиционирования так, чтобы они выходили за экран. Но это кажется слишком громоздким решением.

Может есть вариант как это сделать более просто и элегантно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли Вы это свойство примените, так как поддержка имеется только у `WebKit`:

```css
img{
  max-height:200px;
  -webkit-box-reflect: below 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/women-model-blonde-minidress-red-photography-dress-fashion-hair-clothing-color-girl-beauty-lady-leg-blond-hairstyle-photo-shoot-abdomen-human-body-136579.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Но вот этот пример может жить :

```css
#img1{
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); 
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1); 
-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); 
  transform: scaleX(-1); 
  filter: FlipH; 
  -ms-filter: "FlipH"; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flip">
  <img id="img1" src="http://st.gde-fon.com/wallpapers_preview/649619_model_poza_figura_krasnoe-plate_plate_www.Gde-Fon.com.jpg" alt="">
<img id="img"src="http://st.gde-fon.com/wallpapers_preview/649619_model_poza_figura_krasnoe-plate_plate_www.Gde-Fon.com.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Но в Вашем примере картинка все равно зеркально отражена, а на примере, который я указал она повернута в ту же сторону что и основная...